# Better way to put different parts of an array spread by all processes into a single final array with MPI in C

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I put this code only as an example so that you can understand what I am looking for:

```
  double *f = malloc(sizeof(double) * nx * ny);
  double *f2 = malloc(sizeof(double) * nx * ny);
  for ( i = process * (nx/totalProcesses); i < (process + 1) * (nx/totalProcesses); i++ )
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < ny; j++ )
    {
          f2[i*ny + j] = j*i;
    }
  }
  MPI_Allreduce( f2, f, nx*ny, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM);
```

And yes, it works, in the end I have the correct result in 'f' and that is what I want, but I would like to know if there is a better or more direct way to achieve the same in order to get efficiency. I tried it with allgather but couldn't get correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I would like to know if there is a better or more direct way to
> achieve the same in order to get efficiency.

No, in the given context, using a [MPI collective routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/mpi-collective-functions) is (in theory) always more efficient than the alternative send/recv. Although is not imposed by the MPI standard a good implementation of it, however, implements MPI collective routines like `MPI_Allreduce` in `log(p)` steps (with `p` being the number of process).

Bear in mind, however, that [MPI_Allreduce](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html):

> Combines values from all processes and distributes the **result back to
> all processes.**

Therefore, if you do need the result in all the processes you can use [MPI_Reduce](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2.x/www3/MPI_Reduce.html):

> Reduces values on all processes to a single value